# mounting a linux network shared directory onto a directory of another linux server

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

I apologize in advance if this a noob question.

I have two servers,
**NFS Server: usanfsd01

LINUX Server: usalnxd01**

I've to mount the **usanfsd01:/nfs/data** directory onto the **usalnxd01:/lnxwd** directory. I know how to do the mount via /etc/fstab. But the only concern is usalnxd01:/lnxwd directory has already some files inside it so because of that the mount is not working. I got no other option but to mount the network share on the lnxwd directory was wondering if there are any other options apart from me having to move the files inside lnxwd directory to somewhere else temporarily and then mount it and then copy the files back.

The concern here is if I move the files inside lnxwd directory even for a while, I'm just worried it might break something else that's being dependent on those files. So I thought I would seek some expert opinion here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try to find under the /lnxwd directory, no files are in use. You can use the following command if you are not aware,

```
fuser -c -u /lnxwd
```

Thing is, after mount you cannot use the files which is already is use under the directory /lnxwd. If there is any files in use, try to stop the program and create a backup of this directory. Once after your successful mount, restore the files back to this share. Note that, those files also available only in share and not in local system